# "Loss" of processes when using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` package in Python to parallelize a simulation over 415700 iterables into 40 different processes (since the computer has 40 CPUs), simply using the [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) method.
Everything seems to be running smoothly at the beginning. However, after some time, there are many less processes being executed, thus slowing down the number of iterations per minute.

For example, after a day or two of simulations, I realise that only ~10 processes are being executed, while there are still more than half of the simulations (~200000) to be executed.
There is no error being printed, or nothing indicating why the number of processes was reduced.
If I manually stop it, and run again, the 40 processes are back in track.
I have not specified the *chunksize*, but I do not think this should be the issue, since there are many tasks still in the queue to be executed.

Do you know why this "loss" of processes could be happening?

Note: Probably I should use `imap` or `imap_unordered`, and set the *chunksize* parameter for better performance, which I will do in the next tests.

**Edit:** The operating system is CentOS Linux 7. It is a server, and I am running my simulations over ssh, and using a `tmux` session.
My python version is `3.8.0`.
My worker function does not return any value. It just saves some values into csv files (using [Filelock](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/)). I use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add some fixed arguments to the worker.

An important note is that I run (only if a condition is met, so only in ~half of the cases) a `subprocess.call` within the worker function in order to execute another software (battblocks from HEASOFT).

Comment: I assume all your code uses a logging service: what do the logs say? And if you're not: step 1 would be to make sure you're using a logging service so you know what each process is doing.

Comment: I am just printing something in each simulation and logging in a file the errors catched each time an exception is raised (inside try-except clauses). In this set of simulations, there were no exceptions logged there. But probably this is not enough... Should I use the `logging` package to have proper logging? What should I log though? Of course the errors if there were any, but what else could I log?

Comment: What does "loss" mean? Some number of processes have physically vanished from your OS's view of processes? They're not vanishing, but some number of processes no longer accumulate any CPU cycles? All processes stick around and accumulate cycles, but at an ever-slower rate? Remember we're flying completely blind here ;-) At least log each time a process begins and finishes each execution of the worker function (e.g., log the time, the process id, and "enter" or "exit").

Comment: Yes, "loss" meaning that they have vanished. I am using Ubuntu, and I check the running processes / tasks with the `top` command. I will log each time a process beings and finishes each execution. Note that it is expected that some excutions will take longer than others

Comment: You cannot verify if processes are still running using `top`, since it only lists top processes by a specified metric. If processes you are interested in have fallen below the top N spots (e.g. when sorting by CPU%, by waiting on I/O), they will not be visible on `top`. Use `ps` or `pstree` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's little info to go on here. Please say more. For example, which version of Python are you using? Do you have plenty of RAM for 40 workers to run simultaneously, or are you pushing your luck?  Is your code pure Python, or does it rely too on extension modules (if so, which ones?)? Does a worker function execute other processes? Does your worker function return a result, or just fall off the end?

That said, if processes are vanishing, that's not a thing `Pool` normally does. They must be dying off for some other reason. For example, I know people have reported problems stemming from the Linux-ish out-of-memory (OOM) process killing workers based on its own whims.

I don't think this is documented: if a `Pool` discovers that a worker process it's managing has gone missing, it creates a brand new worker process to take its place. So your `Pool` should essentially *always* have the number of processes you asked for at the start, even if some do vanish mysteriously.

You can test this yourself by writing a tiny toy program and killing worker processes manually while watching a process manager display. Soon after you kill a worker process, you should see a new one appear by magic. Since it's not documented, I'm not clear on which versions of Python it works under (which is one reason for telling us which version you're using). Works in a current (3.12.1) version, but certainly in some number of versions before that too.

Definitely switch to some version of:

```py
    for r in pool.imap_unordered(worker, iterable):
        pass
```

While in a comment you said you're catching exceptions and logging them, there are mounds of under-the-covers pool-management code, and you can't catch exceptions raised by that stuff. Iterating over the (possibly `None`) results ASAP gives the main program a chance to re-raise such otherwise invisible exceptions ASAP.

In the absence of identifying "the cause", you could also consider passing the `maxtasksperchild=N` argument to the `Pool` constructor. Depending on details (of which, here, we know none), some workers have to use facilities (e.g., database interfaces) that just aren't robust under extended use (e.g., they may leak memory relentlessly). Specifying that option tells `Pool` to terminate a worker after it's run `N` tasks, and start a new worker process to take its place.

Ideally, that would never be necessary. But, in this case, one of the clues we do have is that you don't notice a problem until "after some time". Quantifying that could also help.

I agree it's extremely unlikely that `chunksize` has anything to do with this.

### EDIT

> when I use the free command I can see a total of 125Gb of memory.

Total memory is irrelevant on its own. Use `free -h` to get more human-readable output. You're pushing your luck if, when the program is running, "free" is ever less than - say - 20% of "total".

Note too that, as @Amadan noted in a comment, `top` is trying to be helpful by (at best) burying inactive processes. But we don't care how busy workers are, we only care whether they're still in service. For that reason, as they suggested, `ps` is a better tool.

> About the "after some time", I don't know how to quantify it: In some cases it case 1 or 2 days, and in other cases it is as fast as a few minutes, when some processes start vanishing.

- As just above, we're not yet convinced that any process vanished.
- You *did* just quantify it :-) It's very helpful to know that it can happen "as fast as a few minutes". That all but rules out it's due to bit rot from long-running processes, and that in turn makes fiddling with `maxtasksperchild` most likely useless.

> ... I run (only if a condition is met ...) a subprocess.call within the worker function in order to execute another software (battblocks from HEASOFT).

Another possibly good clue! Python has millions of users, but to judge from a Google search, battblocks is very niche. If it's prone to, e.g., infinite loops or segfaults or ..., in rare cases, there are far fewer people stressing it than there are stressing Python.

Please take care to log whenever a battblocks call is made, and returns, too. While there's no evidence of this, it's *consistent* with what you're seeing if battblocks simply never terminates in some cases, or takes a very long time to complete.

Next step: while not documented, `Pool._pool` is a list of worker processes. Here's an example:

```py
def show_pool_workers(pool):
    for proc in sorted(pool._pool, key=lambda p: p.pid):
        print("pid", proc.pid, "alive?", proc.is_alive(),
              "exitcode", proc.exitcode)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing as mp
    with mp.Pool(5) as p:
        show_pool_workers(p)
        input("kill one manually, then come back and hit ENTER")
        show_pool_workers(p)
```

and output from a run:

```
pid 9660 alive? True exitcode None
pid 9844 alive? True exitcode None
pid 14228 alive? True exitcode None
pid 14464 alive? True exitcode None
pid 15764 alive? True exitcode None
kill one manually, then come back and hit ENTER
pid 9660 alive? True exitcode None
pid 9844 alive? True exitcode None
pid 12584 alive? True exitcode None
pid 14228 alive? True exitcode None
pid 14464 alive? True exitcode None
```

At the prompt, I manually killed pid 15764, The second block of output shows that it vanished, and a new process with pid 12584 replaced it.

I'd personally be happier if `Pool` blew up loudly when a worker process went missing, but it doesn't. So if we want to detect that, we need our own code. For example, along these lines:

```
def active_workers(pool):
    return {p.pid for p in pool._pool if p.is_alive()}
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    with multiprocessing Pool(40) as pool:
        wpids = active_workers(pool)
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(worker, iterable):
             wpids2 = active_workers(pool)
             if wpids != wpids2:
                 print("OUCH", wpids, wpids2)
```

If worker processes are vanishing, *and* `Pool` knows about it when it happens, this will catch it soon after it happens.

Comment: How can I be sure I have enough RAM? Probably I do because when I use the `free` command I can see a total of 125Gb of memory.

Comment: I have added more details to the question (at least those for which I have an answer for). About the "after some time", I don't know how to quantify it: In some cases it case 1 or 2 days, and in other cases it is as fast as a few minutes, when some processes start vanishing.

Comment: About the `maxtasksperchild`, if the worker does not reach N tasks, then it would not trigger this, so it would not start a new worker process, right? In that case, this would not solve the issue right?

Comment: Thanks - see new long edit at the bottom.